# Add Progress Bar

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, zenity

I would like to include a zenity progress bar for this part of my script:

```
zenity --question --title "GUI" --text "Sync Music to iPad?"
    if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then
    scp -r "$FOLDER" root@192.168.0.188:/var/mobile/Media/Music
    ssh root@192.168.0.188 'rm /var/mobile/Media/Music/"All Songs"/*'
    ssh root@192.168.0.188 'find /var/mobile/Media/Music/ -name "*.mp3" -exec ln -s {} /var/mobile/Media/Music/"All
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [GNOME Documentation](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/zenity-progress-options.html.en), it looks like `--progress` should get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a simple `zenity` progress like this:

```
yes|zenity --progress --pulsate --text="Doing the job" --timeout 5
```

or perhaps with a:

```
kill $(pidof zenity)
```

after completion.